# Rails application not able to detect the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Even after specifying the route in `routes.rb` my `Rails` application gives me following error when I hit `http://localhost:3000/pages` in the browser.

**Ruby Version:** 2.2

**Rails Version:** 5.0

**Error:**

```
No route matches [GET] "/pages"
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<h2>Welcome Home</h2>
<p>After your long journey through rocky mountains and dry dust bowls you have finally neared the end.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root 'pages#home'` only sets up the root route. This will match only `localhost:3000/` and not `localhost:3000/pages`

You want to add something like

`get 'pages', to: 'pages#home'` to allow `/pages` to work correctly.

Check out http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to learn more about routing and your `routes.rb` file.